# Generating a derived table in SSRS from last purchases in two different SQL Server tables, and then joining with a third

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Suppose I have three tables:

- one of customer info with a unique ID (`CUST_ID`)
- one of customer pants purchases 3 columns (`CUST_ID, PANT_TYPE, PANT_DATE`)
- one of customer shirts purchases 3 columns (`CUST_ID, SHIRT_TYPE, SHIRT_DATE`)

Additionally, I wish to exclude certain pant types and certain shirt types (PANT_TYPE IS NOT 'JEANS', SHIRT_TYPE IS NOT 'TUXEDO'), and only grab the most recent pant purchase and shirt purchase.

So, ideally, I would end up with final table like this:

```
CUST_ID, LAST_PANT_TYPE, LAST_PANT_DATE, LAST_SHIRT_TYPE, LAST_SHIRT_DATE
```

For four hours at work I tried to get this [solution to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/3800572#3800572), but the 'OVER' statement breaks SSRS and causes problems in testing the query and even drops the fields randomly at times. So, I am thinking derived tables of some sort might work.

I am pretty new to SQL and have learned a lot trying to solve this, but I need to get there STAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *Common Table Expressions* for your derived tables, you query could look like this:

```
WITH
  p (cust_id, pant_type, pant_date, rn) AS (
    SELECT cust_id, pant_type, pant_date,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY pant_date DESC)
    FROM Pants WHERE pant_type NOT IN ('JEANS')
  ),
  s (cust_id, shirt_type, shirt_date, rn) AS (
    SELECT cust_id, shirt_type, shirt_date,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY shirt_date DESC)
      FROM Shirts WHERE shirt_type NOT IN ('TUXEDO')
  )
SELECT c.cust_id, 
  p.pant_type AS last_pant_type, p.pant_date AS last_pant_date,
  s.shirt_type AS last_shirt_type, s.shirt_date AS last_shirt_date
FROM Customers c
  LEFT JOIN p ON c.cust_id = p.cust_id AND p.rn = 1
  LEFT JOIN s ON c.cust_id = s.cust_id AND s.rn = 1;
```

Comment: i think you missed the part where I can't use OVER?

Comment: Yes, indeed. What database version are you using? "OVER" will not break anything, but of course you need at least SQL Server 2008.

Comment: OVER technically works, but it breaks the interface in SSRS's query designer, that I need to use to test out my query and see how the results shape up because I'm a noob.

Comment: @traggatmot - There are plenty other issues with the SSRS query designer - don't rely on it's limitations to determine what you can do in an SSRS query.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `APPLY` operator, e.g.:

```
SELECT
    C.CUST_ID
    , PANT.PANT_TYPE LAST_PANT_TYPE
    , PANT.PANT_DATE LAST_PANT_DATE
    , SHIRT.SHIRT_TYPE LAST_SHIRT_TYPE
    , SHIRT.SHIRT_DATE LAST_SHIRT_DATE
FROM
    CUSTOMER C
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            P.PANT_TYPE
            , P.PANT_DATE
        FROM PANT P
        WHERE
            P.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID
            AND P.PANT_TYPE <> 'JEANS'
        ORDER BY P.PANT_DATE DESC
    ) PANT
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            S.SHIRT_TYPE
            , S.SHIRT_DATE
        FROM SHIRT S
        WHERE
            S.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID
            AND S.SHIRT_TYPE <> 'TUXEDO'
        ORDER BY S.SHIRT_DATE DESC
    ) SHIRT
```

Using `OUTER APPLY` (as opposed to `CROSS APPLY`) ensures that none of the customers will be filtered out (`NULL` will be returned in the 'PANT' or 'SHIRT' columns if there is no data for the customer in their respective tables).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making data and using ROW_NUMBER to identify the last purchase.

```
SELECT 1 AS CUST_ID
INTO #CUSTOMERS 
UNION 
SELECT 2
UNION 
SELECT 3
UNION 
SELECT 4

SELECT 1 AS CUST_ID, 'SLACKS' AS PANT_TYPE, CAST('1/1/2017' AS DATE) AS PANT_DATE
INTO #PANTS
UNION
SELECT 1, 'CARGO SHORTS', CAST('2/2/2018' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 1, 'SLACKS', CAST('3/3/2018' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 2, 'CARGO PANTS', CAST('2/2/2017' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 2, 'SLACKS', CAST('4/4/2018' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 3, 'CARGO PANTS', CAST('4/1/2018' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 3, 'SLACKS', CAST('5/8/2017' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 4, 'CARGO SHORTS', CAST('2/2/2018' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 4, 'SLACKS', CAST('3/3/2018' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 4, 'CARGO PANTS', CAST('2/2/2017' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 4, 'SLACKS', CAST('4/4/2018' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 4, 'CARGO PANTS', CAST('4/1/2018' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 4, 'SLACKS', CAST('5/8/2017' AS DATE)

SELECT 1 AS CUST_ID, 'POLO' AS SHIRT_TYPE, CAST('1/1/2017' AS DATE) AS SHIRT_DATE
INTO #SHIRTS
UNION
SELECT 1, 'POLO - LONG SLEEVE', CAST('2/2/2018' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 1, 'POLO - LONG SLEEVE', CAST('3/3/2018' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 2, 'POLO', CAST('2/2/2017' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 2, 'POLO - LONG SLEEVE', CAST('4/4/2018' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 3, 'T-SHIRT', CAST('4/1/2018' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 3, 'POLO', CAST('5/8/2017' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 4, 'T-SHIRT', CAST('2/2/2018' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 4, 'POLO', CAST('3/3/2018' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 4, 'T-SHIRT', CAST('2/2/2017' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 4, 'POLO - LONG SLEEVE', CAST('4/4/2018' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 4, 'T-SHIRT', CAST('4/1/2018' AS DATE)
UNION
SELECT 4, 'POLO', CAST('5/8/2017' AS DATE)

SELECT C.CUST_ID, P.PANT_TYPE, P.PANT_DATE, 
    S.SHIRT_TYPE, S.SHIRT_DATE
FROM #CUSTOMERS C
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CUST_ID, PANT_TYPE, PANT_DATE, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY CUST_ID ORDER BY PANT_DATE DESC) AS ROW_NUM FROM #PANTS) P ON P.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID AND P.ROW_NUM = 1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CUST_ID, SHIRT_TYPE, SHIRT_DATE, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY CUST_ID ORDER BY SHIRT_DATE DESC) AS ROW_NUM FROM #SHIRTS) S ON S.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID AND S.ROW_NUM = 1
```